# jQuery - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have - what I think - should be a very simple `jquery` script. When the `register_hyperlink` anchor is clicked, I am presented with the `alert` box, as expected; but after I click the OK, I am getting an error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

The code block is below. I can't see anywhere that there are unbalanced parenthesis as the error states. The code below is inside the  element of my html page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#register_hyperlink").click(function() {
      alert('Hello');
     });
  });
</script>
```

Does anyone have any idea how to go about debugging this? I've been at it for a while now, but am having zero luck.

Thanks!

Comment: The console error log will have some details about the source of the error and a stacktrace can you share them too? is there a `onclick` attribute in the `a` element

Comment: That code is fine. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Only thing i can think of is trying .on('click', function(){ instead, you are using the most recent jquery lib , maybe .click is deprecated by now

Comment: in jsfiddle works perfectly

Comment: @JayRizzi No, `.click()` isn't deprecated...a simple check in the jQuery docs would confirm that. It's just a shortcut for `.on("click"`. And being deprecated doesn't mean it's not available, it means it will be removed in a future build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had:

```
<a id="register_hyperlink" href="javascript:void();">Register an account</a>
```

I changed it to:

```
<a id="register_hyperlink" href="javascript:void(0);">Register an account</a>
```

So that explains it :-)

Answer (score 1):

What have you got in the href attribute of your anchor? Alternatively do you have a an onClick attribute in the anchor or are you catching it anywhere else?

You are not preventing the default behaviour of the anchor and you may have a syntax error in the href. That would be my first guess.

You could change your posted function to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#register_hyperlink").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert('Hello');
    });
});
```

If you test with this function you may find, as  Matt Ball points out that your problem was indeed elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

you could use

```
<a id="register_hyperlink" href="javascript:;">Register an account</a>
```